# How to use paramiko with pexpect?

Tags: python, paramiko, pexpect

I successfully open an ssh connection with paramiko.

As i have want to use pexpect for automatic interaction with the system on the remote end, I would like to to pass the paramiko connection to [pexpect.fdpexpect.fdspawn](https://pexpect.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/fdpexpect.html), but the two don't fit together.

Paramiko gives me a file descriptor, but the [documentation is explicit about the fact that it cannot be used for reading or writing](https://docs.paramiko.org/en/stable/api/channel.html#paramiko.channel.Channel.fileno). What I need is a bidirectional file-descriptor for reading and writing, but I have a hard time figuring out how to connect the dots.

I understand why this piece of code doesn't work, but I don't know how to create something that does work.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import pexpect
import pexpect.fdpexpect
import paramiko

sshc = paramiko.client.SSHClient()
sshc.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
sshc.connect('192.0.2.1', username='redacted', password='redacted',
             look_for_keys=False, allow_agent=False)
io = pexpect.fdpexpect.fdspawn(sshc.invoke_shell().fileno())

io.sendline('')
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to use [Fabric](https://www.fabfile.org/) which defines itself as:

> Fabric is a high level Python (2.7, 3.4+) library designed to execute
> shell commands remotely over SSH, yielding useful Python objects in
> return. It builds on top of Invoke (subprocess command execution and
> command-line features) and Paramiko

Comment: Fabric has competitors trying to do the same thing on top of the same underlying tools (f/e, [`paramiko-expect`](https://github.com/fgimian/paramiko-expect)). I'd be hesitant to call it "the answer", especially somewhere library recommendation requests are explicitly off-topic.